# LPF and HPF filters in ENVI

Tags: geotiff-tiff, filter, envi, digital-image-processing

Since we know about convolution filter in image processing, it is basically a matrix applied to an image and a mathematical operation comprised of integers and it works by determining the value of a central pixel by adding the weighted values of all its neighbors together.

Question: In Envi software, we apply a convolution filter under:-

`the Filter  >  Convolutions and Morphologytab`

Now there we have a default 3×3 **LPF **(low-pass filter)**** and **HPF**(High pass filter), On the basis of their usage/kernels, how exactly these filters work?

Comment: you would like to how the default is selected as 3x3 or how does a 3x3 filter works?

Comment: Yes and also how it works? what is the logic behind it's working?

Comment: @YogeshChavan kindly answer my query now!